# XSLT to remove name space prefix and also empty tags at the sametime

Tags: xml, xslt

I am looking out for an XSLT which can remove namespace prefix as well as empty tags , I have searched in forum I found two separate XSLT to achieve this, I am trying to find an XSLT which can do both.

Please note I am not very well verse in XSLT , so seeking help here.

source xml:

```
<ns1:DSBookingDetail xmlns:ns1="http://example.com">
    <ns1:BookingNo>000123</ns1:BookingNo>
    <ns1:SeqNo>1</ns1:SeqNo>
    <ns1:LineType>Item</ns1:LineType>
    <ns1:ProductCode>Box</ns1:ProductCode>
    <ns1:ProductCategory></ns1:ProductCategory>    <!-- empty tag -->
</ns1:DSBookingDetail>
```

target xml:(After name space prefix was removed and empty tags )

```
<DSBookingDetail>
    <BookingNo>000123</BookingNo>
    <SeqNo>1</SeqNo>
    <LineType>Item</LineType>
    <ProductCode>Box</ProductCode>
</DSBookingDetail>
```

Comment: I edited your source XML to be _well-formed_.

Answer (score 1):

You can reconstruct all elements by using their `local-name()` as new name and check if their content is empty at the same time.

```
<xsl:template match="*[normalize-space(.)]">     <!-- only match non-empty elements -->
  <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">            <!-- reconstruct element without namespace-prefix -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />   <!-- recurse further -->
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```